# Github Action fails to install Python

Tags: python-3.x, github, github-actions

I'm quite new in setting Github CI pipelines, I'm trying to set a Github action that firstly installs Python, but it always fails at this stage. Here is my .yml action file:

```
# This workflow will install Python dependencies, run tests and lint with a single version of Python
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-python-with-github-actions

name: Python application

on:
 push:
   branches: [ main ]
 pull_request:
   branches: [ main ]

 jobs:
  build:

  runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Set up Python 3.8
  uses: actions/setup-python@v3
  with:
    python-version: "3.8"
- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install flake8 pytest
    if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
- name: Lint with flake8
  run: |
    # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
    flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
    # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
    flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
- name: Install DVC
  uses: iterative/setup-dvc@v1
- name: Configure DVC
  run: |
    dvc pull
- name: Test with pytest
  run: |
    pytest
```

The process fails and here is the bug I got
[image]
Any help please?

Comment: Did you try using `python-version: 3.8` instead of `python-version: "3.8"` (without double quote) in your workflow?

Comment: Yes, It didn't solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, but copy/paste error messages to make them searchable. It looks like installing python was successful, but pip install fails. Please try to make your question simpler by removing all unnecessary code and create a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask